# auto focus the same textbox on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, autofocus

I need to focus the text box which on blur moves to next box. but, if an error is detected it needs to be focused again.

here is my code

```
  <input type="text" id="error_code'" name="errorcode[]" onblur="validate_code(this.id)"/>

function validate_code(id){
var error_code=$("#"+id).val();

 if(isNaN(error_code))
    {
         $('#'+id).val("");  
         $('#'+id).focus();
    }
}
```

however this id not setting focus to same text box. tnx.

EDIT: Am able to validate and get result. But, my question is on re-focusing the text box if error is returned...

Comment: check if you can alert correct id.

Comment: yep that am getting, even the values..

Comment: What value you are getting? may be it is never entering in `if` condition because it is failing.

Comment: is the value of the text box set to null??

Comment: @Bongs getting whatever value is entered in text box

Comment: @rutwikreddy no nothing is set...

Comment: I just checked your code and it seems to be working fine, you can check how I tested it at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/phM7s/4/

Comment: @VishalDeep no its not!, its focusing next textbox.. :)

Comment: @sree isn't this right according to your condition? If the entered value is not a number, the focus will stay in the current textbox, otherwise, it'll move to the next one.

Comment: @VishalDeep working for me in Chrome. :) only when I blur with mouse click it clears the textbox but don't show cursor in textbox :)

Comment: @sree, can you check this link http://jsfiddle.net/phM7s/7/
I made a few changes to the code.

Comment: @VishalDeep that was a cunning way to make it work, i loved it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.. this works perfectly:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="error_code"/>
```

**Jquery blur function:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#error_code").blur(function(){
var error_code=$(this).val();
if(isNaN(error_code))     {  
$(this).val("");            
$(this).focus();    
}    
});
});
```

Comment: Not working, am using mozilla...and i need to work that in mozilla :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tryout something like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="error_code" name="errorcode[]" onblur="validate_code(this.id)"/>
    </div>
    <script>
        function validate_code(id){
        var error_code=$("#"+id).val();
               if(isNaN(error_code)) {
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('#'+id).val("");  
       $('#'+id).focus();
    }, 0);
        }
 }
    </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

In case of jQuery its already tries to set focus to the field. It will block further focus events to the field. To you need to hack it out by something like this.